# How do I set the most recent Python installation as default version?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, updates

[python update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyHJ2.png)

I have Python 3.5 installed on my (LinuxMint) computer by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

However, when I run python -V, it shows that Python 2.7 is being used.

How do I tell the system to use the updated version of Python?

Comment: Run `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: Please post the text of what you tried here instead of posting a link to a picture, which might be deleted at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You have python2.7 installed and you already have a link to the `python2.7` executable so that when you simply run `python`, it actually runs `python2.7`. When you install python3.5, that link still exists.

You should either run `python3` (or `python3.5`) or you should replace the link with a new link like so (assuming python3.5 in /usr/bin):

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
```

Add `sudo` before the command if you don't have permissions to create the link and your user is a sudoer.

Answer (score 1):

More dynamically,

```
ln -sf $(which python3) $(which python)
```

which forces the creation of symbolic link from python3 to python.

Comment: What if there's no python installed yet?